# Generate a report to by passing multiple map values with Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm an amateur to java programming, and I'm having problem calling the report from iReport. Also i have problem in *NumberFormatException* of Java, it always occurs when i leave a textField empty that accepts Integers and BigDecimals. I'm not sure if my code in the next lines are correct.

First i created this variables.

```
private String USERID;
private String BRANCHCODE;
private BigDecimal CURRCD;
private BigDecimal CURRRT;
private String DATE;
private String CFSNO;
private String CFSPREF;
private int INTMNO;
private int GACCTRANSID;
private int ASSDNO;
private BigDecimal POLICYCODE;
```

Then i create the connection:

```
 private Connection conn() {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("Connection", "connetion user", "connection pass");
        return conn;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The last following lines, these is where i get really confused.
I'm not sure if using hashmap is the right way to pass parameters.
Also, when i try to run the program and leave the ASSDNO and POLICYCODE parameters empty, it returns a *NumberFormatException*.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     {                                         
    try {
        USERID = jTextField1.getText();
        BRANCHCODE = jTextField2.getText();
        CURRCD = BigDecimal.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText()));
        CURRRT = BigDecimal.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText()));
        DATE = jTextField5.getText();
        CFSNO = jTextField6.getText();
        CFSPREF = jTextField7.getText();
        INTMNO = Integer.parseInt(jTextField8.getText());
        GACCTRANSID = Integer.parseInt(jTextField9.getText());
        ASSDNO = Integer.parseInt(jTextField10.getText());
        POLICYCODE = BigDecimal.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(jTextField11.getText()));

        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("P_USER_ID", USERID);
        map.put("P_BRANCH_CD", BRANCHCODE);
        map.put("P_CURR_CD", CURRCD);
        map.put("P_CURR_RT", CURRRT);
        map.put("P_CFS_DATE", DATE);
        map.put("P_CFS_NO", CFSNO);
        map.put("P_CFS_PREF", CFSPREF);
        map.put("P_INTM_NO", INTMNO);
        map.put("P_GACC_TRAN_IN", GACCTRANSID);
        map.put("P_ASSD_NO", ASSDNO);
        map.put("P_POLICY_ID", POLICYCODE);

        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\Users\\G40-70\\Desktop\\giacr252\\GIACR252_UCPB_AGENT.jrxml");
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, map, conn());
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
    } catch (NumberFormatException | JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

THE JRXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="GIACR252_AGENT" language="groovy" pageWidth="572" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="572" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="882a52e1-0cdd-4a3f-9647-42ff5bd67e94">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="182"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="P_USER_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="P_BRANCH_CD" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="P_CURR_CD" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<parameter name="P_CURR_RT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<parameter name="P_CFS_DATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="P_CFS_NO" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="P_CFS_PREF" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="P_INTM_NO" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="P_GACC_TRAN_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="P_ASSD_NO" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="P_POLICY_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM TABLE (giacr252_nia_pkg.get_giacr252_agent(
    $P{P_USER_ID},
    $P{P_BRANCH_CD},
    $P{P_CURR_CD},
    $P{P_CURR_RT},
    TO_DATE($P{P_CFS_DATE}, 'MM-DD-YYYY'),
    $P{P_CFS_NO},
    $P{P_CFS_PREF},
    $P{P_INTM_NO},
    $P{P_GACC_TRAN_ID},
    $P{P_ASSD_NO},
    $P{P_POLICY_ID}
    ))
ORDER BY policy_id]]>
</queryString>
<field name="INTM_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="USER_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="ISS_CD" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="AGENT_CD" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="GACC_TRAN_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="POLICY_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="ASSD_NO" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="PREM_SEQ_NO" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="PERIL_SNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="GROSS_PREMIUM" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="COMMISSION_RT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="PREMIUM_AMT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="COMMISSION_AMT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="INPUT_VAT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="WHOLDING_TAX" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="LINE_CD" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CURRENCY_CD" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="CURRENCY_RT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="SHORT_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CFS_NUMBER" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CFS_DATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CF_INTM_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CF_AGENT_CD" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CF_INTM_TYPE_NO" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CF_POLICY_NO" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CF_ASSD_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CF_COMMISSION_RT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="CF_WTAX_TOT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="CF_IVAT_TOT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="CF_PROV_FUND" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<variable name="COMMISSION_AMT_1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{COMMISSION_AMT}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="inputvat" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{INPUT_VAT}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="wtax" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{WHOLDING_TAX}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<group name="GROUP_BY_AGENT">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{AGENT_CD}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="78">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="77" height="12" uuid="62e82cc5-2db8-42f0-8214-b8ca158c5d88"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[NAME OF AGENT]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="77" y="0" width="5" height="12" uuid="92acccdd-ae8f-4a2c-bb4e-5247ca7bfb94"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="339" y="0" width="62" height="12" uuid="42ecf447-b8df-4f37-9a6f-ecad8045c194"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[CFS NUMBER]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="401" y="0" width="5" height="12" uuid="db1fa860-1782-45b4-9eb6-f1ca486bc7b7"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="401" y="11" width="5" height="12" uuid="eb31534c-cb77-4fb4-b120-6ce386fc39ed"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="339" y="11" width="62" height="12" uuid="e6fa12e0-ed1e-4f45-ba33-81f1f5f55c98"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[DATE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="33" width="225" height="12" uuid="d2d2d08a-6b5e-4bd4-b9cb-a70c72ca0ed4"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[COMMISSIONS FOR THE FOLLOWING POLICIES    :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="478" y="55" width="81" height="12" uuid="de72c9be-3b85-4de1-a26b-91f8ab017aaa"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Amount ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="350" y="44" width="222" height="12" uuid="41575d6c-a5bf-44b2-a0c9-1e981763e393"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Commission]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="55" width="142" height="12" uuid="e5850580-bce3-47f9-83be-c0f8c82ed0b2"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Policy No. / Bill No. / Assured]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="299" y="55" width="51" height="12" uuid="30e25be3-6d81-41b1-acf2-5c42f313ca13"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Peril]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="214" y="55" width="80" height="12" uuid="9d35d697-1a0d-437e-9a9d-7d65880892b8"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Gross Premium ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="428" y="55" width="50" height="12" uuid="ad79cf60-7d3d-41d3-ba90-c4a55aafadd0"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Rate ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="350" y="55" width="78" height="12" uuid="ff5240f3-69f0-498d-8f15-18e73a562be5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Premium ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="350" y="66" width="78" height="12" uuid="2b13079a-5c35-41b3-9c30-9cc7a597a1f6"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[--------------------------------]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="428" y="66" width="50" height="12" uuid="136abc9c-f858-4c2c-808b-f0899d5cad20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[--------------------]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="299" y="66" width="51" height="12" uuid="73656519-d007-4529-aa6e-819a4ba4879a"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[---------------]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="66" width="214" height="12" uuid="cebfad08-8243-4ba5-9709-bb77ccf9a51e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[---------------------------------------------------------------------]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="478" y="66" width="81" height="12" uuid="ee634310-27eb-40dd-b81b-19fd6d6de116"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[--------------------------]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="214" y="66" width="80" height="12" uuid="ca1bf9e0-433c-47e6-99b3-8581e7400503"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[-----------------------------]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="91" y="0" width="212" height="12" uuid="c54742b2-21e2-4adf-8f45-b948cf8ac0fd"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CF_INTM_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="415" y="0" width="131" height="12" uuid="d037f8a6-43ec-4eee-95e6-3e504da82a88"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CFS_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="415" y="11" width="131" height="12" uuid="85b72d09-f10c-4c59-8bda-b3679ad09ac0"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CFS_DATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
<group name="GROUP_BY_POLICY_NO" keepTogether="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{POLICY_ID}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="24">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="204" height="12" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="f07abff6-d941-4ca6-a57f-8b63fd959f5c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CF_POLICY_NO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="12" width="204" height="12" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="843517b7-c85d-4ff0-98f6-13ca2c2abac8"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CF_ASSD_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="214" y="0" width="80" height="12" uuid="19f7a5df-6470-4757-9ec9-371223c70f82"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GROSS_PREMIUM}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="299" y="0" width="259" height="24" uuid="ac0ea0aa-03f3-4c92-be54-f5f1f012bd80"/>
                <subreportParameter name="P_GACC_TRAN_ID">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_GACC_TRAN_ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_CURR_RT">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_CURR_RT}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_POLICY_ID">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_POLICY_ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_CFS_PREF">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_CFS_PREF}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_BRANCH_CD">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_BRANCH_CD}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_CFS_DATE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_CFS_DATE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_CURR_CD">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_CURR_CD}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_INTM_NO">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_INTM_NO}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_CFS_NO">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_CFS_NO}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_USER_ID">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_USER_ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="P_ASSD_NO">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_ASSD_NO}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "GIACR252_UCPB_AGENT_PERIL.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
<summary>
    <band height="145" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="340" y="49" width="104" height="12" uuid="c9aaa360-aaa7-47be-b676-64af663dd319"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Commission net of Wtax]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="339" y="85" width="129" height="12" uuid="bf793e49-5bd5-4a1d-856e-8f645d75a554"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Total Actual Net Commission]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="340" y="61" width="104" height="12" uuid="2a9db061-487a-466d-b7b5-292dc56530b6"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Input Vat]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="340" y="25" width="92" height="12" uuid="e6b61b90-5b99-48cb-a450-045d78bda6b6"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Withholding Tax]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="339" y="13" width="51" height="12" uuid="d2e4fd22-1bc1-402d-a460-880a0ba9e90a"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Total]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="477" y="97" width="81" height="12" uuid="27c6c46a-3e41-4a77-bd13-05bc21b9ced5"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[=======================]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="477" y="73" width="81" height="12" uuid="af4e469f-813e-4d96-a773-e4ce815a6f0b"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[------------------------------------]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="477" y="37" width="81" height="12" uuid="81fbc870-1b04-43d3-840f-c0f42c2da013"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[------------------------------------]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField pattern="#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="477" y="13" width="81" height="12" uuid="4d7c9266-a1ad-46a4-b4c8-0c663caf3b5a"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{COMMISSION_AMT_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="477" y="25" width="81" height="12" uuid="8ef57895-fadf-4de5-b5b9-0bd67dac513d"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{wtax}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="477" y="61" width="81" height="12" uuid="7cd3ef58-1b3a-44b8-b0bf-0fedf12ab3c2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{inputvat}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="477" y="49" width="81" height="12" uuid="c86e3021-a9f7-4d4b-9473-e1d1bfd0f6e0"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{COMMISSION_AMT_1} - $V{wtax}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="477" y="85" width="81" height="12" uuid="773dc968-c369-4358-95c4-d8d81af06e19"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{COMMISSION_AMT_1} - $V{wtax} + $V{inputvat})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="11" y="85" width="203" height="12" uuid="4be6ce83-319e-4f22-aeaa-c4fa69389402"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["/" + $F{CF_INTM_TYPE_NO} + "-" + $F{INTM_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The stacktrace (I left 2 textFields(ASSDNO, POLICYCODE) empty, causing ireport to call all the data).

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at ProductionReport.GIPI_COMM_INVOICE.jButton1ActionPerformed(GIPI_COMM_INVOICE.java:257)
at ProductionReport.GIPI_COMM_INVOICE.access$000(GIPI_COMM_INVOICE.java:28)
at ProductionReport.GIPI_COMM_INVOICE$1.actionPerformed(GIPI_COMM_INVOICE.java:100)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicButtonListener.java:303)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1663)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2929)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6310)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: `Also, when i try to run the program and leave the ASSDNO and POLICYCODE parameters empty, it returns a NumberFormatException` - You should post the full stacktrace. You should post the *jrxml* file

Comment: I have added the stackTrace(If i'm correct), and the jrxml.

Comment: Have you find the solution, if yes, could you please guide me.?